# Cannot see xml comments from dll in a project

Tags: .net, xml-comments, xml-documentation

I created a .dll with xml commented functions and subs, like:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the Path of this assembly
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>Assemblypath</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function GetactiveProgrammPath() As String
        Dim exeName, exedir As String
        exeName = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location
        exedir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeName)
        Return exedir
    End Function
```

I reference the .dll in another project and cannot see the xml comments. Any idea why? I followed the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/dd722812.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually build the xml file? The page you linked to doesn't seem to mention this.

> Right click your project -> Settings -> Build -> Check "Xml documentation file".

When you build your project, you should now produce both `MyProject.dll` and `MyProject.xml` files.
Your other project should be able to find the xml documentation now.